# How list and filter stacks with boto3 cloudformation resource?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I want to get a list of stacks based on a give set of states. I am aware of a solution using the boto3 client for cloudformation, e.g. from the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html?highlight=describe_stacks#CloudFormation.Client.list_stacks):

```
response = client.list_stacks(
    NextToken='string',
    StackStatusFilter=[
        'CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'CREATE_FAILED'|'CREATE_COMPLETE'|
        'ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'ROLLBACK_FAILED'|'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|
        'DELETE_IN_PROGRESS'|'DELETE_FAILED'|'DELETE_COMPLETE'|
        'UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|
        'UPDATE_COMPLETE'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED'|
        'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS'|'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'|
        'REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS',
    ]
)
```

(side note: I think the `|` should be `,`, but anyway)

However, I understand that the "recommended" way is using boto3 resources to access the AWS services. Unfortunately, the boto3 cloudformation resource has not method to list and filter stacks (see [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html?highlight=describe_stacks#service-resource)).

I would like to avoid looping over all stacks and check each retrieved stack object for its status.

The only way I found so far, is the work around by accessing the client of the resource, though it feels a bit hacky and there is no way to filter for instance on the stackname.

```
cf = boto3.Session().resource('cloudformation')
cf.meta.client.list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=['ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'])
```

**Question**: Any idea how I could get something like `list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=..)` for `cf`, which is a `cloudformation.ServiceResource` object that allows to filter on the status and the stackname?

Comment: For an environment with a significant number of stacks, probably using the boto3 client is the way to go, so that the filter is applied AWS side instead of you filtering it client side.  I liked this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228551/listing-more-than-100-stacks-using-boto3

Answer (score 3):

Interesting; that's an unfortunate asymmetry in the boto API. That said, I would stick with the resource and use a list comprehension vs. going through the `meta` attribute:

```
statuses = ['ROLLBACK_COMPLETE', 'CREATE_COMPLETE', 'UPDATE_COMPLETE']
cfn = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
stacks = [stack for stack in cfn.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in statuses]
```

By dropping back to the `meta.client`, you get a dict response rather than Resource objects. If that's ok, just use cloudformation client instead of the resource. The comprehension will return `Stack` resource objects instead of dicts

Ultimately, either works and it's a matter of preference; just avoid mixing paradigms if you can.

Comment: Thanks @bimsapi that's basically my current solution. However, like this I have to iterate over the full set of stacks.

Comment: Understood. Without API support, that's the only option, and the overhead is modest. I think the more important issue is deciding on resource vs. client and sticking with it in your code for consistency.

Comment: cf.staks.all() only lists "active" stacks, so it doesn't work for statuses like DELETE_COMPLETE.  In other words, you will need to use client.list_stacks to query for those statuses instead.

stacks1 = cf.meta.client.list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=['DELETE_COMPLETE'])
stacks2 = [stack for stack in cf.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in ['DELETE_COMPLETE']]

stacks1 get you list of deleted stacks while stacks2 will always give you an empty list.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old post, but I thought this detailed answer would be helpful to others.

```
import boto3
COMMA = ','
GOOD_STATES = ('CREATE_COMPLETE,UPDATE_COMPLETE,UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE').split(COMMA)
BUSY_STATES = ('CREATE_IN_PROGRESS,ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS,DELETE_IN_PROGRESS,UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS,UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS,UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS,UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS,REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS').split(COMMA)
BAD_STATES  = ('CREATE_FAILED,ROLLBACK_FAILED,DELETE_FAILED,UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED,DELETE_COMPLETE,ROLLBACK_COMPLETE').split(COMMA)

cfn_rs = boto3.resource('cloudformation')

#use one of the following that serves your purpose

good_stacks = [stack for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in GOOD_STATES]
good_stack_names = [stack.name for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in GOOD_STATES]

busy_stacks = [stack for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in BUSY_STATES]
busy_stack_names = [stack.name for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in BUSY_STATES]

bad_stacks = [stack for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in BAD_STATES]
bad_stack_names = [stack.name for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status in BAD_STATES]

my_stacks = [stack for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status not in BAD_STATES]
my_stack_names = [stack.name for stack in cfn_rs.stacks.all() if stack.stack_status not in BAD_STATES]
```

Please note the difference between the following two:

- ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Stack creation process started and rolled back after some resources were created due to some failures. Usually, you need to delete this stack before creating a stack with the same name.
- UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Update process started on an existing stack but rolled back after modifying some resources due to some failures.